# Bad positioning with interval for markers

Tags: php, position, marker

I can display all the markers from a request, but they point with a little gap in my map.

For instance, New York is pointed near Quebec. If I zoom into the map, all the markers move close to the right position.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.1&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var timeout = 600;
    var address_position = 0;
    var address = [
        <?php
        $_list="";
        $_unicite=array();
        foreach($search_data as $k => $item)
        {
            $_address=trim($item->meta_value);                              

            if(!empty($_address))
            {
                if(!in_array($_address,$_unicite)){
                    $_unicite[$item->post_id]=$_address;
                    $_list.='"'.$_address.'",';
                }
            }                               
        } 
        if(!empty($_list)) {
            $_list=substr($_list,0,abs(strlen($_list)-1));
        }
        echo $_list;
        ?>             
        ];
    var link = [
         <?php
            $_list2="";
            $_unicite2=array();
            foreach($search_data as $k => $item)
            {
                $_link=trim($item->post_id);                                

                if(!empty($_link))
                {
                    if(!in_array($_link,$_unicite2)){
                        $_unicite2[$item->post_id]=$_link;
                        $_list2.='"'.$_link.'",';
                    }
                }                               
            }       
            if(!empty($_list2)) {
                $_list2=substr($_list2,0,abs(strlen($_list2)-1));
            }
            echo $_list2;
         ?>             
         ];
    var title = [
        <?php
        $_list3="";
        $_unicite3=array();
        foreach($search_data as $k => $item)
        {
            $_title=trim($item->post_title);                                

            if(!empty($_title))
            {
                if(!in_array($_title,$_unicite2)){
                    $_unicite2[$item->post_id]=$_title;
                    $_list3.='"'.$_title.'",';
                }
            }                               
        }    
        if(!empty($_list3)) {
            $_list3=substr($_list3,0,abs(strlen($_list3)-1));
        }
        echo $_list3;
        ?>             
        ];
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://www.bookyourparis.com/images-site/beachflag.png',
        new google.maps.Size(28,54),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(14,54)
    );
    function addMarker(position)
    {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address[position]}, function(results, status)
        {
            address_position++;
            if (address_position < address.length)
            {
                setTimeout(function() { addMarker(address_position); }, (timeout));
            }
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
            {
                setTimeout(function() { addMarker(position); }, (timeout * 3));
            }
            /**
            if (address_position < address.length)
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
                {
                    setTimeout(function() { addMarker(position); }, (timeout * 3));
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() { addMarker(address_position); }, (timeout));
                }
            }
            /**/
            else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {   
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);                
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map,  
                    title:address[position],
                    icon: image,
                }); 
                var contentString = '<div id="content_bulle"><div id="bodyContent_bulle" style="margin-top:5px;">'+
                '<h1 style="font-size:1.5em">'+title[position]+
                '</h1><h2 style="font-size:1.2em">'+results[0].formatted_address+
                '</h2><p style="color:#AF1A40"><a target="_blank" href="?p='+link[position]+'">View</a></p>'+
                '</div></div>';
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString,
                    maxHeight: 100
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            } 
        });
    }
    function codeaddress() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,  
        }   
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        addMarker(address_position);
    }
    function centerMap() 
    {
        map.setCenter(markers[markers.length-1].getPosition());
    } 
    jQuery(window).load( function(){
        codeaddress();
    }); 
 //]]>
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 940px; height: 420px;border:1px solid #999"></div>
```